# How to restore dynamically created HTML table/controls on Page refresh?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

In my webpage, I am creating HTML table/div/controls at run-time. But, on Page refresh, it disappears.. What is the best way to retain/restore all the dynamically created HTML controls with their values?

ASP.NET and code behind is C#. Mostly I am using HTML controls, JQuery/JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

All controls must be rebuilt in `Page_Load` so that event handlers and value binding can occur. So, if you create the controls initially in an event handler then you need to cache enough data in `Session`, or `ViewState`, so that you can rebuild those controls on `Page_Load`.

A lot of times a basic `Tuple` will work to provide enough information for those controls to be recreated. A little note though. You're going to need to ensure you set the `ID` property the first time they are built **and** when they are rebuilt. That's how value binding occurs.